# Windows 8.1 cannot select active window nor open start screen

Tags: windows, virtualbox, windows-8.1

Occasionally, after some time, Windows seems to not be able to switch active windows and always acts as if no window were active; basically, as if the Desktop were always selected. Even the start screen starts displaying and then immediately stops as if Desktop were selected.

The only thing I can think that might be screwing it up is my VirtualBox. Any idea what might be causing it?

Comment: Shutdown your virtual box to confirm it's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try Alt+Tab. Additionally, ensure your windows key isn't depressed (Stuck)